# Microsoft Access 2007 Integration with Microsoft Visual Source safe 6.0

Tags: ms-access-2007, visual-sourcesafe

I am attempting to integrate an access program into Microsoft visual source safe 6.0.
I have downloaded an extension which allows source control access in access.
Here is the site that I used to guide me in my project

http://www.kevingao.net/sourcesafe/integrating-sourcesafe-vss-with-access-2007.html

I have imported the access program into source safe. But I am having trouble with access with multiple users on the network.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem referred to is that multiple developers (users) can't check out the code from VSS.  I am having the same problem with an Access database and came across this when researching the problem.  VSS will not let anyone except the user who created the project check it out.

Comment: Can you cite a source for that?

Answer (score -1):

Your app should be split into front end (forms/reports/etc.) and back end (data tables only). Only the front end needs to be in VSS, since only the front end has code in it. Also, each user should have an individual copy of the front end. It seems like you're trying to share a single front end. This will never work, and if you look at your app properly (the front end is the "program" -- you don't have multiple users running Word from a shared copy, so why would you share your Access "program"?), it will be obvious why you shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: OK, anonymous cowardly downvoter -- what in this answer could you possibly see as being wrong? Or are you just the usual wimpy idiots hating on Access who have no real evidence for why you're against it because you really don't know anything at all about how Access/Jet/ACE works?

Comment: David, the tone of that comment might, itself, be an encouragement to downvote you.